# getElementsByTagName and then a.textContent returns "↵" on Li 3 every time

Tags: getelementsbytagname

```
<script>
function SearchVideosFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("SearchVideosInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("SearchVideosUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; ++i) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have the above script that runs on Keyup that searches the `<li>` in an `<ul>` which works brilliantly however on `<li>` number 0,1,2 it works fine then on 3 it returns `txtValue = "↵"` then continues to work fine from there

Ive tried moving content of `<li>` but it does not matter what happens it always returns the "↵" on the `<li>` 3

What on earth is causing this????

Comment: Can you add the source HTML? What is populating your `<li>` elements in the DOM?

Comment: Oh... sorry on further investigation i had missed one closing </a> on the following line and that caused it to miss that li. even though wordpress didn't get bothered by that